# Unable to get responseText from an AJAX call in laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, object

I have an AJAX call that looks like this:

```
function getPosts(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.post("get-posts",
        function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        });
}
```

And in my **routes/web.php**, I have:

```
Route::post('get-posts','PagesController@getPosts');
```

And the controller_function looks like this:

```
public function getPosts(){
        $posts = DB::table('users_queries')->get();
        echo json_encode($posts);
    }
```

But the problem is that the console logs an empty string. To assure that I was converting a php object, I called the `gettype($posts);` function as well and it returned object. Then I thought the problem might be in the `<script>` tags and tried this `typeof(data)` and that returned string as well which made sure that the data was string. But when I ran `console.log(data.length);`, I was shocked because it logged 0. But I was able to do things like:

```
public function getPosts(){
    $posts = DB::table('users_queries')->where('id', 1)->first();
    echo $posts->author;
}
```

And everything ran sweet, but I am unable to get the whole json. So what is the problem in my code? I am unable to figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Why are you not using **Eloquent** instead of **DB**. Eloquent has `toJson()` which converts collection into JSON serialized string easily. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-tojson

Comment: replace your echo with this -> return response(['data'=> $posts])

Answer (score 0):

Return your response as JSON: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#json-responses

```
public function getPosts(){
    $posts = DB::table('users_queries')->get();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'data'   => $posts
    ]);
}
```

Comment: That showed `500 Internal Server` error and didn't work!

Comment: have a look at `storage/logs/laravel.log` or whichever log file you are logging to for the error you are getting, it may be easier to clear the log file and run the ajax